# How to use String.prototype.startsWith filter with html table

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, filter

How to use String.prototype.startsWith filter with HTML table

This is example of my project using json but I have to use filter array on my project.

http://jsfiddle.net/8kkg3/3471/

this is code of filter i want to use it with the table.

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
            String.prototype.startsWith = function (str) {
                return this.substring(0, str.length) === str;
            }
        };
        const str ='John';
        let result =str.startsWith('j');
        console.log(result);
```

Comment: `J` is not `j`. Try calling `toLowerCase` first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"J" == "j"
```

Statement above will be evaluated as False. Both `resultA` and `resultB` below will be True.

```
const str = 'John';
let resultA = str.startsWith('J');
let resultB = str.toLowerCase().startsWith('j');

console.log(resultA);
console.log(resultB);
```

Comment: Thank you for this point, and do you know how to use it with this code with html table and filter it by input textbox http://jsfiddle.net/8kkg3/3471/

Comment: Here's an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) from w3school.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/8kkg3/3519/) an update to your fiddle which filters the table based on the input.

---

Btw, your markup is a bit off you shouldn't put the header "User Name" into the table body. You were also missing `tbody` and `thead` elements.

Also, the use of `var` is considered deprecated. You should use `let` and `const` instead ([see here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75) for a guide).

Comment: Thank you so much :) i will use const

Comment: another question, How to add another input filter in the table, already have input for username. Now, i need to add another input for Job, and I update my file. http://jsfiddle.net/aliaati/8kkg3/3536/

Comment: You just need to copy, paste & adapt: 1. add an input handler `$(...).on('change', f)` for the job input; 2. inside the handler `f`` apply the same logic as for name change but with the appropriate selectors for the job column.